# How to store a part of an array in different array in python

Tags: python, arrays

Let's say I have an array

```
A=[1 2 3 2 4 5 6]
```

Now i need to store first 3 values of array A into array B

I am doing

```
b.append(a[1])
b.append(a[2])
b.append(a[3])
```

but I am unable to get any output.

Comment: `b = a[:3]`. Also, what do you mean by not getting any output?

Comment: what do you mean exactly? What does `print(b)` give you? And what do you expect to see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider to use slices

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = a[:3]

print b #print(b) for Python 3.x
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html

Comment: A slightly better (imo) resource would be: http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/

Comment: ok this is fine but if u want element 2,3,4 in new list then how to do that??

Comment: b = a[1:4], you should really read about that slicing stuff, it's awesome :-)

Answer (score 0):

You don't even have to declare a second empty list.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = list(a[:3])
```

Answer (score 0):

### Input list

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print a
```

### Output list (using slides)

```
b = a[:3]
print b
```

### Output list (taking desired elements)

```
b = [a[0], a[1], a[2]]
print b
```

### Output list (appending desired elements)

```
b = []
b.append(a[0])
b.append(a[1])
b.append(a[2])
print b
```